# How do I simplify this circuit to find resistor voltage?

Tags: voltage-divider, basic, kirchhoffs-laws

In my circuits class, I am presented with the following exercise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYdNzd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem is to find the voltage across resistors A and B.  The most likely solution (given the section) is to use simplification by analysis.  I tried to solve for B first.  My attempt included cutting the circuit in two parts (all of the resistors and just B), simplifying the part of the circuit that was *not* B, and then solving the resulting circuit.  This yielded a parallel circuit.

I know that is not supposed to yield a parallel circuit which implies a direct voltage path from the source to resistor B.

The book as has a similar example, but in this one the two ohm resistor is to the *right* of the 3 ohm resistor, making simplification vastly easier.  (I seem to have missed the lecture on this.)

Could someone be so kind as to point me in the right direction?

Comment: I got it!  The first part, at least.  Thanks anyways.  Just to be nice I'll post what I did when I get the time....

Comment: Normal simplification works. 3 || 6 = 2 Ohms, 2+2= 4 Ohms again 4 || 4 is 2 Ohms. So, voltage of A w.r.t Common Point (6V source negative terminal) is 6V*2/(2+4) = 2V, Current through 2 Ohms +3||6 circuit is 0.5Amps.So, voltage across 3|6 Ohms resistor is 2*0.5A = 1V. So, Va=2V, Vb=1V==> VAB = 2-1 =1V

Answer (score 1):

Your approach, if not your execution, is sound .

If you're familiar with Thevenin equivalent circuits, you know that you can replace the entire circuit to the left of the B resistor with a voltage source in series with a resistor.  Once you've done this, voltage division will give you the voltage across B.

For A, replace all the resistors to the right of A with an equivalent resistor which is in parallel with A.  Then, once again, apply voltage division to find the voltage across A.

Comment: Thevenin circuits are in the chapter after next.  I've got A so far... I apparently was caught on an error in the simplification process itself.  *I hope.*